# Ubuntu 16.04 NIC card issue

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, virtualbox

I am experiencing something really strange.

I was fixing my VMs because I wasn't able to run `sudo apt-get update`. I fixed this problem, but this happened and I don't know how this happened or how to fix it. They are static IPs using a NAT interface.

[image: Server 1]

[image: Server 2]

Please guide me to the correct path.

Comment: Your VMs need *separate* IPs they can't both have the same IP address.

Comment: They have different IP's, when i ping the hostname it shows the IP but on the it seems like the pictures diodn't upload properly

Comment: then start by uploading the CORRECT IMAGES for your VMs.

Comment: uploaded seems like one of them fixed itself but the other server still has the wrong config, ive changed the the /etc/network/interface and rebooted and changed my MAC.

Comment: fixed it, i had to change it the interface, omg im so noob at this!

Answer (score 0):

You have two major networking configuration failures going on here:

1. Both VMs are configured to have the same exact IP address, **and**
2. Both of the VMs the same exact MAC address.

**Both of these issues must be resolved before you can get things working properly.**

---

***IP Conflict***

You can't have this happen in a sane NAT'd environment - this is called an **IP Conflict** and you need to resolve it.

Set one of the VMs to have a different static IP.  Then restart both VMs.

---

***MAC Address Conflict***

You also have a MAC address conflict.  That is, **both VMs have the same MAC address**.  NAT and network routing is *heavily dependent* on each system, VM or otherwise, having **unique MAC addresses**.

Go into the configuration of your second VM's network interface at the virtualization system level.  Edit the network interface and generate a **new random MAC address**

---

**Only after you have done both of the above stated things to fix both issues**, fully power off both VMs and then power them back on.  Then see if they can reach out properly.

NOTE: If neither machine properly works, then you need to check the host OS to see if the traffic is being denied/firewalled.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Thomas! I am using virtualbox will changing the MAC on the VM break my servers?